# Customer name is missing in welcome message after login

Tags: magento2, template, theme, header

In header, there is a welcome message which can be configured in the Magento backend.

However after login, i found that the customer fullname is not insert into the welcome message,(i.e. always showing the Default message only) and i am not sure where to update & debug this kind of js in magento 2.

Can anyone give some advice on it?

Answer (score 0):

If your cache system is disabled, just enabled it and will work again.

Thats what works for me.